# C# TCP HTTP Chunked Encoding конец потока

Tags: c#, http, tcp

Данные приходят сюда

```
private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
  AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;

  if(e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
    //increment the count of the total bytes receive by the server
    Interlocked.Add(ref m_totalBytesRead, e.BytesTransferred);
    Console.WriteLine("The server has read a total of {0} bytes", m_totalBytesRead);
    //echo the data received back to the client
    e.SetBuffer(e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
    bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.SendAsync(e);
  }
  else {
    CloseClientSocket(e);
  }
}
```

если например такой запрос

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

7\r\n
Mozilla\r\n 
9\r\n
Developer\r\n
7\r\n
Network\r\n
0\r\n 
\r\n
```

Как в коде получить запрос как string когда он полностю будет получен?

Comment: А в чем проблема это декодировать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov откуда серверу знать сколько их будет?)

Comment: смотрите формат кодирования. Если в куске заявлено 7 байт - значит, их там будет 7, ни больше, ни меньше. А дальше - следующий кусок, со своей длиной.